# How to create Category Tree in GoLang

Tags: go, recursion, tree

I have a struct like that.

```
type Category struct {
    ID              int     `json:"id"`
    MetaDescription string  `json:"metaDescription" gorm:"column:metadescription"`
    MetaTitle       string  `json:"metaTitle" gorm:"column:metatitle"`
    Name            string  `json:"name" gorm:"column:categoryname"`
    Order           int     `json:"order" gorm:"column:categoryorder"`
    ParentId        int     `json:"parentId" gorm:"column:parentid"`
    Rank            float64 `json:"rank" gorm:"column:rank"`
    Url             string  `json:"url" gorm:"column:catname4seo"`
}
```

I'm fetching this data from a database and I want to manipulate it to create a category tree. My tree would be like that

```
type CategoryTree struct {
    ID            int            `json:"id"`
    Name          string         `json:"name" gorm:"column:categoryname"`
    Url           string         `json:"url" gorm:"column:catname4seo"`
    SubCategories []CategoryTree `json:"subCategories"`
}
```

Normally, I am a JavaScript dev and a newbie in GoLang so especially static type made me harder. That's why I couldn't achieve it. Can you help me to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an algorithm question. Just iterating over the Category list, and push elements into CategoryTree. Go code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Category struct {
    ID              int     `json:"id"`
    MetaDescription string  `json:"metaDescription" gorm:"column:metadescription"`
    MetaTitle       string  `json:"metaTitle" gorm:"column:metatitle"`
    Name            string  `json:"name" gorm:"column:categoryname"`
    Order           int     `json:"order" gorm:"column:categoryorder"`
    ParentId        int     `json:"parentId" gorm:"column:parentid"`
    Rank            float64 `json:"rank" gorm:"column:rank"`
    Url             string  `json:"url" gorm:"column:catname4seo"`
}

// load db data by CategoryTree instead of Category
type CategoryTree struct {
    Category
    SubCategories []*CategoryTree `json:"subCategories"`
}

func main() {
    input := []*CategoryTree{
        {
            Category: Category{
                ID:       1,
                ParentId: 0,
            },
        },
        {
            Category: Category{
                ID:       2,
                ParentId: 1,
            },
        },
        {
            Category: Category{
                ID:       3,
                ParentId: 1,
            },
        },
        {
            Category: Category{
                ID:       4,
                ParentId: 2,
            },
        },
    }

    tree := makeTree(input)

    output, _ := json.MarshalIndent(tree, "", "  ")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(output))
}

func makeTree(list []*CategoryTree) *CategoryTree {
    dataMap := make(map[int]*CategoryTree, len(list))
    var rootNode *CategoryTree

    for i := range list {
        // root node has min ParentID
        if rootNode == nil || rootNode.ParentId > list[i].ParentId {
            rootNode = list[i]
        }

        // list to map
        dataMap[list[i].ID] = list[i]
    }

    // build tree
    for i := range list {
        parentNode, ok := dataMap[list[i].ParentId]
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        if parentNode.SubCategories == nil {
            parentNode.SubCategories = []*CategoryTree{}
        }
        parentNode.SubCategories = append(parentNode.SubCategories, list[i])
    }

    return rootNode
}
```

and output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "metaDescription": "",
  "metaTitle": "",
  "name": "",
  "order": 0,
  "parentId": 0,
  "rank": 0,
  "url": "",
  "subCategories": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "metaDescription": "",
      "metaTitle": "",
      "name": "",
      "order": 0,
      "parentId": 1,
      "rank": 0,
      "url": "",
      "subCategories": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "metaDescription": "",
          "metaTitle": "",
          "name": "",
          "order": 0,
          "parentId": 2,
          "rank": 0,
          "url": "",
          "subCategories": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "metaDescription": "",
      "metaTitle": "",
      "name": "",
      "order": 0,
      "parentId": 1,
      "rank": 0,
      "url": "",
      "subCategories": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, it didn't work. First error is about list[i]. Since rootNode is a pointer I can't use rootNode = list[i]. I changed it &list[i]. There seems no error but I run the code and "parentNode.SubCategories = append(parentNode.SubCategories, list[i])" this line gave an error.

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: @FurkanTopaloğlu Sorry, i just give you my idea here, while my code not been test. now i change my answer, and give you complete code that i had run and test. You can try it.